# C# XDocument right way to escape symbols

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Hello I'm struggling with escaping in xml, problem is my output is escaped 2 times and I dont understand why its happening. 
Code below:

```
        private static string FixSingleEncoding(string data)
    {
        //data?.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("&#34;", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
        return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(data); //SecurityElement.Escape(data);//
    }

    private static XDocument FixEncoding(XDocument instance)
    {
        XNamespace naming = instance.Root.Name.Namespace;
        var result = instance.Descendants(naming + "dataset").ToList();
        var count = result.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            result[i].Value = FixSingleEncoding(result[i].Value);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static bool CreateNewDataset(string path, string data) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("CALL");
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(MasterLocation, path));

        xdoc = FixEncoding(xdoc);


        XNamespace df = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;


        XElement root = new XElement(df+"changeSet");

        root.Add(new XAttribute("id", "My Name"));
        root.Add(new XAttribute("author", "Test"));


        string final = data;

        XElement innerelement = new XElement(df + "data", final);
        innerelement.Add(new XAttribute("endDelimiter", "GO"));
        root.Add(innerelement);

        xdoc.Root.Add(root);
        xdoc.Save(Path.Combine(MasterLocation, path));


        return true; 
    }
```

Problem is when I first time load xml file and use method CreateNewDataset it retrieves all data from xml file and unescape old data, so I put FixEncoding method, but then another problem showed up, now it escapes two times, how do I know that exactly two times, well using VS Code and converting XML Entity to string, it needs to converted 2 times to readable string, CreateNewDataset method is called only once, but data escaped two times, what do I miss here?

entered data

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                    FROM   sysobjects 
                    WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[table1]') 
                        and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 0)
```

orginal code before CreateNewDataset:

```
        <changeSet id="Test" author="My Name">
    <data endDelimiter="GO">
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                    FROM   sysobjects 
                    WHERE  id = object_id(N&apos;[dbo].[table1]&apos;) 
                        and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N&apos;IsProcedure&apos;) = 0)
      </data>
</changeSet>
```

AFTER createnewdataset(without FixEncoding)

```
<changeSet id="Test" author="My Name">
    <data endDelimiter="GO">
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                    FROM   sysobjects 
                    WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[table1]') 
                        and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 0)
      </data>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: You don't have to encode anything, XDocument will do so when it's serialized to a string. XML encoding is different from HTML encoding anyway, so that `FixEncoding` method can only *break* any valid XML document.

Comment: XDocument.Load will decode any encoded content too. What is the *actual* problem? Did you try to read some text value which came back XML encoded? Perhaps you tried to insert an XML fragment as  a string into another XML element, which resulted in the text getting encoded again (as it should)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I dont put fixencoding in the end nothing is escaped single ',<>, & left unescaped

Comment: You don't have to escape anything. Nor encode or decode. What you're doing can only break your code. Post an example that actually demonstrates the problem *without* any attempt to "fix"

Comment: just refresh page I updated my post

Comment: @tizer1 Given that your "AFTER createnewdataset(without FixEncoding)" is valid XML, what's the problem?

Comment: single quotes are not escaped that means, bad output.

Comment: Single quotes don't *need* to be escaped in XML. Try running the XML through an online XML validator -- it's fine

Comment: The output is fine. The **unencoded** SQL fragment is fine too. Are you sure the problem isn't caused by some other part of the code that expects encoding where none is needed?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well I used to encode entire SQL code using VS code STRING TO XML Entity which converted all xml special characters, now it converts everything except single quotes, old application which used to read this xml used to throw errors with bad characters detected, so thats why I used VS code and everything is fine, but now without escaping single quotes it would be interesting to see if it crash or work fine.